# Null before each element in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of colors that I am trying to use to color another list, I have a function that makes the list and I call that function and set it to a variable in another function. If I try to print the list in that function, it returns Null in front of every color, how do I stop this from happening?

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please list your code.

Comment: Please replace the screenshots with code.

Comment: Missing ; after AppendTo (twice). Once after While.

Answer (score 3):

The `Null` before each element is actually a product of `Null` and color. In the definition of `uColorPascalsTriangleDot`, you have `clst=uColorPascalsLinesDot[number,n]` directly in front of the `While[]` loop. Mathematica sees this as `uColorPascalsLinesDot[number,n]` multiplied by the return value of `While[]` which is `Null`. Hence the output. The solution is to add a semicolon after the clst definition: `clst=uColorPascalsLinesDot[number,n];`.